# Kernel Panic - Not Syncing : Attempted to Kill init?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, sync

After I removed my RAM, I got the following error:

```
Kernel Panic - Not Syncing : Attempted to Kill init !
```

So I checked it a lot of times and it's working, but my Windows can't login and shows me a *Blue Screen* and Linux shows me the above error. My laptop freezes when I try to boot another OS such as a *Live* or *Rescue* version.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you remove the RAM when the battery and power were disconnected from the laptop? What happens when you reinstall the RAM and then reconnect the power and battery and try to start Ubuntu?

Comment: acctionlly i remember the battrey was on the laptop but the laptop was off, but i had some updates failue on my windows so i keep reboot it from button btw i have lubuntu & windows on same harddrive  i try to boot from usb but not working recovrey mode too

Comment: What happens if you reinstall the RAM with the power and battery disconnected?

Comment: i didnt but i tried all ,  i removed the cms-battery & hard-drive all power & i have acces only to grub command line

Comment: i wanna know if i there is a way to remove all from hardrive i dont care about data i wanna remove all then install lunix again if you understand me sir .

Comment: If you can boot a Lubuntu installer DVD or USB drive, you should be able to tell it to use the whole drive for Lubuntu.

Comment: i already try but showing me the the same kernel panic error when i try with windows usb boot its frozzen on loading files

Comment: Can you get the BIOS (or UEFI) to load the DVD or USB drive directly without going through Windows?

Comment: i can get to bios but u didnt understand me sir, it's when i boot to usb drive (windows) it's blocked & case of usb boot to (linux) show me the same error of kernel

Comment: You can try [Memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) to see if there's a problem with your RAM. They have "Free Edition" images that fit on floppies, CDs, DVDs, or USB.

Comment: ok , i have last question sir , what if i took my hard drive & plug it into my other laptop then format it is that ok ?

Comment: Yes, formatting should be fine, but you shouldn't install the OSes that way, since the hardware will probably be different.

Comment: sir it's look like the memtest is blocked i mean frozen !

Comment: I think that your hardware is damaged. You'll need the assistance of a repair technician to find what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a defective piece of hardware such as:

- One of your memory modules (RAM) may be damaged or the slot on the motherboard may be damaged
- Hard drive or it's controller (SATA) may have been damaged
- A defective motherboard or USB bus

In your question you mention that attempting to boot the Live CD version of Ubuntu is crashing. This is a good indication that there is a piece of faulty hardware, although it is possible for the live version to make use of your disk. **My advice is to unplug your disk and try the Live CD version**. If it still crashes you likely have defective hardware and my advice is to try to run a memory/RAM test such as memtest86.

Comment: sir it's look like the memtest is blocked i mean frozen !

Comment: That means your RAM is broken or the motherboard is broken.

Comment: It might also be a RAM module not being seated properly.

Comment: hey am soory to anoying u , i did removed the hard drive & test memtest again in same frozem as last time , how can i know it's not my motherboard

Comment: The only way to realistically know if it's the motherboard or RAM is to try the RAM in another motherboard, which might also be dangerous. You can try different RAM slots or using one RAM stick at a time to narrow it down.